# How can i get values from 3 different columns into single column in another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
  select cons_id,teh_id,local_id,panchayt_id,war_id,ha_id from b...; 
  select rep_value_id from val;`
```

i need to get the above  values into single column in another table.
how can i solve it by a query or using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in oracle sql .

```
Insert into VAL_TABLE (ID,COMMON_FIELD) values (VAL_TABLE_ID.nextval, ( SELECT CONS_ID || TECH_ID || LOCAL_ID from TABLE_B));
```

Or in MySQL

```
Insert into VAL_TABLE (ID,COMMON_FIELD) values (1, ( SELECT concat( id, type, details)  from TABLE_B ) );
```

Comment: select cons_id+teh_id || pan_id || bo_id || loc_id || war_id 
 as report from tableA where publication_date_id=8 group by 
cons_id+teh_id || pan_id || bo_id || loc_id || war_id  I tried like dis but i m not getting exact answer which i requied plz help to do dis

Comment: check if you are using mysql or oracle sql .. i gave you both options, meanwhile i ll have a look on your posted query

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UPDATE my_table SET col1=    
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',val.rep_value_id,cons_id,teh_id,local_id,panchayt_id,war_id,ha_id) 
FROM b,val);
```

Comment: I'm getting error like dis Error Code: 1265
Data truncated for column 'report_level_value_t' at row 1)

Comment: UPDATE voter_age_info_t SET report_level_value_t=    
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',constituency_id,tehsil_id,local_election_body_id,panchayat_id,ward_id) 
FROM booth limit 1);

Comment: @user2541378- That error usually occurs when there are either null values or datatypes dont match or size of data is too big to fit in that column of that datatype.

Comment: check datatype and size for report_level_value_t